# subtracting count between two table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using MySQL

How I can count with subtracting record from another table.
For example, count = tab1 - tab2

Table: tab1

```
+-------------+----------------+
| studnetId   +   batchId      +
+-------------+----------------+
+    1        +      1         +
+-------------+----------------+
+    2        +      1         +
+-------------+----------------+
+    3        +      1         +
+-------------+----------------+
+    4        +      1         +
+-------------+----------------+
+    5        +      2         +
+-------------+----------------+
+    6        +      2         +
+-------------+----------------+
+    7        +      2         +
+-------------+----------------+
```

Table: tab2

```
+-------------+----------------+
| studnetId   +   batchId      +
+-------------+----------------+
+    1        +      1         +
+-------------+----------------+
```

Expected Result

```
+-------------+----------------+
| count       +   batchId      +
+-------------+----------------+
+    3        +      1         +
+-------------+----------------+
+    2        +      2         +
+-------------+----------------+
```

Comment: I am counting student Id

Comment: When `batchId` is `2`, shouldn't the `count` be `3`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another approach using an `outer join`:

```
select t1.batchId, count(t1.studnetId) - count(t2.studnetId) as cnt
from t1 
       left join t2 on t1.batchId = t2.batchId and t1.studnetId = t2.studnetId 
group by t1.batchId
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c691a/1)

And I assume when `batchId = 2`, the `count` should be `3`, not `2` as in your expected results.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use `not exists`:

```
select count(*), batchid
from tab1 t1
where not exists (select 1
                  from tab2 t2
                  where t2.studnetid = t1.studnetid and t2.batchid = t1.batchid
                 );
```